# Not able to reference Javascript functions inside jQuery wrapper

Tags: javascript

I have custom module called interface, through which I'm adding a javascript file. This code is in plain old javascript, no jQuery, and has been working for me.

I now want to be able to add some jQuery functions to this code, I thought this would be possible since jQuery and javascript should be compatible with each other, right?

So here's a simplified example of what I'm doing inside the .js file:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.interface = {
    attach: function()
    {
        function foofunction() {
        // execute some code
        }
    function WelcomeScreen()
    {
        Screen.apply( this );
        this.html = function(){
        return "<p></p>";
        };
this.activate = function(){
document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "<a id=\"button\" onClick\"foofunction()\">Test</a>";
        };
        }

    }
    }
})(jQuery)
```

This code results in the following error in Chrome dev tools:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: foofunction is not defined
```

My guess is that somehow the required jquery wrapper or the drupal behaviors wrapper are causing the functions to no longer be 'global'.

One obvious answer, I think, is rewriting everything in proper jQuery syntax. But I'm interested in how to make these javascript functions compatible with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

First off, onClick misses an `=` sign. Secondly, Chrome is right. From the point of view of the `<a id="button">` element, the function is not visible even though it seems to be in scope of `WelcomeScreen` function. That's because it's not the function that invokes it, but the element on a page. Try `onClick="Drupal.behaviors.interface.foofunction()"`. But better off - make it unobtrusive by removing the `onClick` attribute and saying at the `document.ready` level:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.interface = {
    // code
    }

    $(function(){
      $('#button').live('click', Drupal.behaviors.interface.foofunction);
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Of course this is just a rudimentary suggestion, you might want to optimize the code further. If you're using jQuery 1.7+, you'd rather use `.on()` than `.live()`.

Comment: By the document.ready level, you mean inside the Drupal.behaviors? This is giving me `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'foofunction'`

Comment: adding the code to my answer for better formatting

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. So this is outside the Drupals.behaviors {} and the subsequent attach: function() {}? It's still giving me `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'foofunction' `

Comment: Oops, I guess we're missing invoking `Drupal.attachBehaviors(document)` before the `#button` line.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I should get a rest today rather than mess up someone's code. I bet it's something simple.

Comment: Arthur don't worry. Good idea, just wrong code ;)

Answer (score 1):

Artur is basically right - "Drupal way " is to attach events in behaviors. Here is code I'm using without problems:

```
(function($) { 
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule= {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      function test(param) {
        alert($(param).attr('token'));
      }

      $(':input', context).on('keyup change', function(){
        test(this);
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Or simpler:

```
(function($) { 
  Drupal.behaviors.mymodule= {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      function test() {
        alert($(this).attr('token'));
      }

      $(':input', context).on('keyup change', test);
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Rewrite your code to that syntax, make sure you are using [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update), and you should be good.